# Integrate TinyMCE

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I need to install Tinymce in Drupal 8 as default text editor.

I have searched  for a solution but there is no much information.

I have deduced that the 'old' module wysywig  (an RTE's manage module) is now called Text Editor, and within it, there is the CKEditor.

I can't find the way to make Tinymce works on Text  Editor as is CKEditor at the moment.

I have tried to  put the module files in `webroot/libraries/tinymce`, in `webroot/modules/contrib/tinymce` and even in `webroot/core/modules/tinymce` but it doesn't be displayed in the `Extend` tab as module.

After that, reading more articles I have supposed that it comes built-in with this module (Text Editor ~ former Wysiwyg) but I can't enable it in no way.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know no one has integrated other editors as tight as CKEditor is in core.

The Editor module in the core is the 'new'/similar module to WYSIWYG from Drupal 7. It's API needs to be utilized to integrate your editor of choice to Drupal. It isn't just a matter of copying and pasting editor packages into a folder. You have to wire it up to Drupal.

It all starts at `core/modules/ckeditor/src/Plugin/Editor/CKEditor.php` where the `EditorBase` class is extended.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!editor!src!Plugin!EditorBase.php/class/EditorBase/8.2.x

See the API for more:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21src%21Annotation%21Editor.php/class/Editor/8.2.x

It is likely just easier to use CKEditor unless there is some specific functionality TinyMCE does that CKEditor does not.

Comment: I have to create several new "buttons" for the rte. So I will follow your advice and I will create CKEditor plugins for this buttons.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is by far easier to create new buttons for CKEditor than implement an entire new editor, thats for sure. Plenty of examples out there where existing plugins are already integrated, like Color Button. https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton

Comment: Here's an implementation of a "custom" wysiwyg as an alternative to CKEditor. https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_md